# Insert space before tick with d3 format

Tags: svg, d3.js

Why isn't this inserting space before tick text?

```
d3.format(' >10')
```

I've tried it with non break whitespace too and that didn't work.

Comment: You can set the `dx` on the `text` to `1em` to emulate that effect. Text in `<text>` is white space insensitive.

Comment: Or set xml:space="preserve" on the text so it's not whitespace insensitive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are the two solutions presented in the comments: http://jsfiddle.net/5Rm2s/1/

```html
<svg height="100px" width="100px">
    <text x="10" y="25"> Text</text>
    <text x="10" y="50" xml:space="preserve"> Text</text>
    <text x="10" y="75" dx="1em">Text</text>
    <line x1="10" y1="10" x2="10" y2="90" stroke="red"></line>
</svg>
```

In D3:

```js
svg.append('g')
   .classed('no-space', true)
   .attr('transform', 'translate(' + 25 + ',' + 10 + ')')
   .call(xAxis);

svg.append('g')
   .attr('with-space-preserve', true)
   .attr('transform', 'translate(' + 25 + ',' + 60 + ')')
   .call(xAxis)
   .selectAll('text')
   .attr('xml:space', 'preserve');

svg.append('g')
   .attr('with-em', true)
   .attr('transform', 'translate(' + 25 + ',' + 110 + ')')
   .call(xAxis)
   .selectAll('text')
   .attr('dx', '1em');
```